# Remove hover event after some time using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Flip cards, based on: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp.

They work well, nonetheless in mobile (since there's no mouse hover) it expects to tap out in order to the card flip to the unhover state. To prevent that, I want to remove hover event after a certain time has passed using javascript when previously pressed.

This is my current JS code:

```
let test = document.getElementById("flip-card");

// This handler will be executed only once when the cursor is hovered

test.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  
  console.log('onHover was excecuted'); // debug thing
  

  // reset the hover after a short delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    test.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); //this needs jQuery, is there anyway to do it with plain Js?
    
  }, 3000);
}, false);
```

Thank you for your advice!

**Append Information**

I want to "unflip" the "flip-card" after certain time has passed, no matter if the cursor is still there.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `removeEventListener`, but it has a catch. You can't remove handlers that are set using `addEventListener('event', function() { ... })`. You have to define your function, meaning your example would look like:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("flip-card");

function handler( event ) {
  
  console.log('onHover was excecuted'); // debug thing
  

  // reset the hover after a short delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    test.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); //this needs jQuery, is there anyway to do it with plain Js?
    
  }, 3000);
}

// This handler will be executed only once when the cursor is hovered
test.addEventListener("mouseenter", handler, false);
```

`removeEventListener` must receive the same capture argument that the `addEventListener` used to add the event in the first place. For example:

```js
test.addEventListener("mouseenter", handler, false);

// Will be removed by
test.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handler, false);
test.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handler, { capture: false });

// But not by
test.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handler, true);
test.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handler, { capture: true });
```

You can read up more about it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

**Update**

After discussing it more, it turns out the issue was more about changing the "active" state when on mobile vs on desktop.

To achieve this, we can stop using `mouse*` events and instead use `pointer*` events. They have the  `event.pointerType` property, which can be either "mouse", "pen", or "touch"

Inside of our handler function, we'll add a conditional to look for `pointerType === 'touch'`.

```js
function handler(event) {
  if (event.pointerType === 'touch') {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

To avoid *too* much complexity, we want to leave all the styling up to the CSS you already wrote. All we need need to do is:

a. Mark the `body` as being "touch compatible".
b. Add a `.active` class to replace `:hover` styles.

Our updated function looks like this

```js
function handler(event) {
  if (event.pointerType === 'touch') {
    event.preventDefault();

    document.body.classList.add('pointer-active'); // arbitrary class name
    element.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

Now we just need to remove the class after a certain amount of delay, which we can do with a `setTimeout`.

```js
function handler(event) {
  if (event.pointerType === 'touch') {
    event.preventDefault();

    document.body.classList.add('pointer-active'); // arbitrary class name
    element.classList.add('active');
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Then we add that back into your original example, it looks like this:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("flip-card");

function handler( event ) {
  console.log('onPointerDown was excecuted'); // debug thing
  
  
  // If the pointer is touch, from mouse, pen, touch
  if (event.pointerType === 'touch') {
    event.preventDefault();

    document.body.classList.add('pointer-active')
    // add the active class
    test.classList.add('active');

    // Remove class after a delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      test.classList.remove('active');
    }, 3000);  
  }
}

// This handler will be executed only once when the cursor is hovered
test.addEventListener("pointerout", handler, false);
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/frankie_tech/pen/BaQqJBK) where you can mess around with it further.

Comment: Thank you Frankie, but it doesn't work, I was reading this page in MDN but I don't know what Im doing wrong (I've just make a codePen with your code but it won't work either) the thing is that it should "unHover" after the timer ends, no matter is the cursor is still there or not (because in mobile it can only detects the hover when the user tap-in.

https://codepen.io/giles14/pen/qBqJVQJ

Comment: Just to make sure, are you looking to keep the card in the "flipped" state for X amount of time after the user taps the card and then "un-flip"?

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's right "un-flip" after a certain time has already passed. (no matter if the cursor is still there)

Comment: I see, then that is less about adding/removing eventlisteners than it is handling state. Since it's just CSS, we can add an `.active` class whenever a touch action happens, and remove it after the delay. We also wanna make sure to target only "tap" users, so we'll use `pointerdown` events instead of `mouseover`. I forked your codepen, so tell me if this is more what you were looking for. https://codepen.io/frankie_tech/pen/BaQqJBK

Comment: Yes frankie, Thanks for your help, your explanation is just what I'm looking for, nonetheless your codepen only works once and only if It's "pressed" using chrome inspector and touch it, but in real mobile phone it doesn't work.

Comment: Yup, i forgot that even touch pointers affect `:hover` despite not being able to "hover" themselves. If you check the codepen again, you can see the changes I've made. Now it works with mobile phones, I checked on my own. When a `pointerout` event occurs, a class is added to the `body` to reset styles. Then the rest hasn't changed.

Comment: That works as a Charm Frankie!, in order to give you the reward you deserve, can you change your main answer (with the solution you implement), to marked as solved?

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: Marked as accepted, it now works using the :active pseudo-element.